# unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, swift, facebook, alamofire

I am trying to login with macbook using code but I keep on getting this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
// API to log an user in
func login(userType: String, completionHandler: @escaping (NSError?) -> Void) {

    let path = "api/social/convert-token/"
    let url = baseURL!.appendingPathComponent(path)
    let params: [String: Any] = [
        "grant_type": "convert_token",
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
        "backend": "facebook",
        "token": FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString,
        "user_type": userType
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):

            let jsonData = JSON(value)

            self.accessToken = jsonData["access_token"].string!
            self.refreshToken = jsonData["refresh_token"].string!
            self.expired = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(jsonData["expire_in"].int!))

            completionHandler(nil)
            break

        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(error as NSError?)
            break
        }
    }

}
```

The error is referring to this line:

```
self.accessToken = jsonData["access_token"].string!
```

and this is LoginViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var bLogin: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bLogout: UIButton!

    var fbLoginSuccess = false
    var userType: String = USERTYPE_CUSTOMER

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
            bLogout.isHidden = false
            FBManager.getFBUserData(completionHandler: {

                self.bLogin.setTitle("Continue as \(User.currentUser.email!)", for: .normal)
                // self.bLogin.sizeToFit()
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil && fbLoginSuccess == true) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "CustomerView", sender: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func facebookLogout(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        APIManager.shared.logout { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                FBManager.shared.logOut()
                User.currentUser.resetInfo()

                self.bLogout.isHidden = true
                self.bLogin.setTitle("Login with Facebook", for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func facebookLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
            APIManager.shared.login(userType: userType, completionHandler:  { (error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.fbLoginSuccess = true
                    self.viewDidAppear(true)
                }
            })
        } else {
            FBManager.shared.logIn(
                withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"],
                from: self,
                handler: { (result, error) in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        FBManager.getFBUserData(completionHandler: {
                            APIManager.shared.login(userType: self.userType, completionHandler:  { (error) in
                                if error == nil {
                                    self.fbLoginSuccess = true
                                    self.viewDidAppear(true)
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Swift 3
Xcode 9
iOS 10.2

I read several texts to find out the causes of this type of error but not succeed.

Comment: [13/Sep/2018 15:52:22] "POST /api/social/convert-token/ HTTP/1.1" 400 214
on terminal

Comment: So apparently `jsonData["access_token"]` is nil?

Comment: how to fit that

Comment: Fix the crash (that's because of the force unwrapping) or fix why `jsonData["access_token"].string` is nil? That's different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is a bad practice to use force unwrap (!) everywhere. Try to avoid it, until you really need it and/or know what are you doing. Here you use SwiftyJSON. It helps you to extract data from JSON in a convenient way. But you shouldn't rely, that you will always get proper JSON from the backend. There are many reasons why it can return wrong JSON and there would not be needed value. There are two options:

1. You can use `.stringValue` instead of `.string` - it will return an empty string instead of `nil`
2. You can do in this way: `if let token = jsonData["access_token"].string {...}` or even use `guard` statement

Here is a good article to understand force unwrapping: https://blog.timac.org/2017/0628-swift-banning-force-unwrapping-optionals/

Comment: I used you 1st option and it works perfectly!

thank you so much, I have been suffering from this problem for a long time

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you have a `!` (*force unwrap* symbol), meaning that you're certain the data will be there; but in fact, the data isn't there - it's `nil`.

Try using a `guard` statement. For example:

```
guard let self.accessToken = jsonData["access_token"].string else {
    // log error message, if desired; then exit the function
    return
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an `if let` statement:

```
if let self.accessToken = jsonData["access_token"].string {
    // do stuff if 'jsonData["access_token"].string' is valid
}
else {
    // do other stuff if 'jsonData["access_token"].string' is nil
}
```

Now, *why* the data is not there (`nil`) - that's another question. Perhaps check your `JSON` function to ensure it's properly processing the JSON response. Also, check to make sure you're getting a valid response:

```
guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode == 200 else {
    // handle a bad response code
    return
}

// handle the good response code stuff after the guard statement
```

Learn about using `if let` to handle possible `nil` values in the Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.2) Guide under *[Optional Binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID333)* in the *Basics* section.

Learn about `guard` statements under *[Early Exit](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID525)* in the *Control Flow* section of the Guide, and also in the *[Statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID524)* section of the Reference.